# Fiddler for mac: bad CPU type in executable: mono32

Tags: mono, fiddler

I'm trying to use `Fiddler` on mac and I download `mono`, everything is ok. But when I type `mono Fiddler.exe`, something goes wrong. I try to google and realized Fiddler‘s graphical interface can just run on 32bit environment. So I run `mono --arch=32 Fiddler.exe` but the command has changed to `mono32` and when I type `mono32`, it shows `bad CPU type in executable: mono32`. And I read some news about MacOS Catalina doesn't support 32 bit application any more. Does this mean I can't use Fiddler on mac or I just need to close graphical interface? If I just need to close the graphical interface, What should I do? Please help me!Thanks!

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere

Comment: ok, I got it. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old Fiddler for Mac was using Mono WinForms to run the user interface on macOS, which is both buggy and 32 bit only. Due to the macOS update, 32 bit apps are no longer feasible.

Telerik is now moving to an Electron based Fiddler UI, called Fiddler Everywhere,

https://www.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere

You can try it out, but it is still in preview and lacks certain features.